# Does macOS Picture-in-Picture have any kind of keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: keyboard, mediaplayer, picture-in-picture

I love using the Picture in Picture feature for use cases like :

- Learning some stuffs, while doing the thing. Not switching windows/apps anymore.
- Binging some shows, movies, while working.

But the thing is, once you missed a thing, you either :

- Close the  Picture-in-Picture mode, go back to that app again, and rewind it back (Mac's  Rewind and  Fast Forward kb shortcuts don't work) (if you happen to not know macOS have a Media Menu bar icon)
- Or click the  Media Menu bar icon, and click  Rewind Back or  Rewind icons.

Check the screen capture here for the demo : https://cln.sh/MDzsof

So is there anyway to control the PiP states/media controls with just keyboard shortcuts :

- Play/Pause
- Toggle PiP on/off
- Hide PiP to the side
- Rewind/Rewind Back
- PiP window placement
- Close the PiP

**Do we have any official Apple documentation regarding kb shortcuts about this?**

***If not, any Siri Shortcuts, Apple Scripts, Applets or app tweaks that can help me with this?***

*PS : to any devs reading, if this solution don't exist yet. This will be a great feature idea for you to solve on your next Mac app.*

Comment: I can't see those icons on either Big Sur or iOS 15

Answer (score 3):

I have created the following Shortcuts that can be activated with <kbd>F9</kbd> and <kbd>F7</kbd> (Tested in macOS Ventura 13):

- [Forward By 10 seconds](https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/ebd6b399c5154367b49124d313aef1ba)
- [Backward By 10 seconds](https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/02cf0870552c43dda69d4a7105c62be8)

Just double check that "Pin in Menu Bar" is checked and "Run with" have the desired keyboard shortcut. This way they will work even if the Shortcuts app is not active:

[image: Screenshot of the settings to double check]

I just noticed some apps already have <kbd>F7</kbd> and <kbd>F9</kbd> shortcuts that will override the action for these shortcuts. So you probably can change them to <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> or whatever shortcut that doesn't conflict with the active app you use regularly with picture-in-picture.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a piece of JavaScript to put a video from the current Safari tab into a Picture-in-Picture window. You need a way to activate it. Personally I'm using a Keyboard Maestro macro to do it.

```
(function() {var video; document.querySelectorAll('video').forEach(function(vid) { if (!vid.paused) video = vid; }); if (video) { video.webkitSetPresentationMode('picture-in-picture') } })()
```